# How to solve this error showing in react project - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, supabase

```
import React ,{useEffect, useState}from 'react'

import Layout from '../components/Layout'

import axios from 'axios';

import TinderCard from 'react-tinder-card'

import MovieCard from '../components/MovieCard';

import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

import { useAuth } from '../auth';


function Home() {

  const auth = useAuth();
  const supabaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
  const supabaseKey = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY
  const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
  
 const fecthMovies = async () => {
  const {data} = await axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie",{
    params:{
      page:Math.random() * 501,
      api_key:"57e19e5c44a33653ce6bfc54743c9e2e"
    }
  })
 console.log(data);
const movie = await data;
setMovies(movie.results);
}
const addTowatchlist = async (movie) => {

const {data, error} = await supabase.from("watchlists").insert({movie_id : movie.id, user_id: auth.user.id})
if(error){
  console.log(error)
}
if(data){
  setMessage("Movie has been added to your watchlist")
}
}

 useEffect(() => {
  if(auth.user){
    fecthMovies()
  }
  
 
 },[auth])





return (
  <Layout>
    {message&&message}
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    {!auth.user && <h2>Please sign up</h2>}

{movies.map(movie => {
 return <>
 <div className="movie-wrapper">
 <TinderCard
 onSwipe={direction => direction === "right"? addTowatchlist():null}
 key={movie.id}>
    <MovieCard movie={movie}/>
  
  </TinderCard>
 </div>
 
 </>
})}

  </Layout>
 )
 

}

export default Home
```

[image: This is the error]

The above given is my Home.js. I don't know why it is showing undefined. I tried to change the 'movies' in 'movies.map' to 'Movies' and so but it didn't do that much. This error is happening when iam trying to add a item to the watchlist table i created in supabase database. And i need to add the movie 'id' iam getting from the item to watchlist table. when i tried this

```
const {data, error} = await supabase.from("watchlists").insert({movie_id : movie?.id, user_id: auth.user.id})
```

like adding ? in 'movie.id' it works but i don't get the id because of the ? . So how can i add the movie id to the list by fixing this error . I really appreciate the help. thanks in advance.

Comment: `addTowatchlist` expects a `movie` parameter and uses its `id` property. You're calling it with no arguments when you swipe right: `addTowatchlist()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please do basic debugging **before** posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined. When used with function calls, it returns undefined if the given function does not exist.

so in the below code user_id: auth?.user?.id it will not be accessible until it is nullish and if it's null it will return undefined instead of crashing an application.

```
const {data, error} = await supabase.from("watchlists").insert({movie_id : movie?.id, user_id: auth?.user?.id})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dex-coder!! Could you edit your answer to explain why your code fixes the issue? That will be more helpful for the poster and for others who come to this question in the future. If an answer on SO is just code, it is likely to get downvoted. Thanks again for contributing and keep it up!

Comment: @AnthonyElliott The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined. When used with function calls, it returns undefined if the given function does not exist. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#:~:text=The%20optional%20chaining%20operator%20(%20%3F.,instead%20of%20throwing%20an%20error. you can read more about optional chaining how it works. Thank you

Comment: great explanation, and much improved answer!